# Does Accelerated Drinker apply to anything other than potions?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, action-economy, potions, traits

I am trying to make a Drunken Brute Unchained Barbarian, and I came across the Combat Trait [Accelerated Drinker](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/combat-traits/accelerated-drinker/). It allows you to drink a potion as a move action, presumably still provoking AOO since that ***ISN'T*** specified as being changed. I also came across a wonderful wondrous item, [Drinking Horn of Bottomless Valor](https://d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/c-d/drinking-horn-of-bottomless-valor/), which allows you to spend 1-3 charges with varying effects based on how many charges you spend. The parts I am focusing on are these:

> So long as the horn has at least one charge remaining, it’s owner can command it to fill with mead or a similar alcoholic drink.

> 1 charge: The drinker gains 1d8 temporary hit points (as if from an aid spell), which last for 1 minute. Using 1 charge is similar to drinking a potion—it takes a standard action and provokes an attack of opportunity (though certain abilities can reduce the action required)

So, would the trait Accelerated Drinker apply to the 1 charge ability? Would it also apply to the mead or similar alcoholic drink?

If not, could anyone propose any way to speed up drinking in combat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It only applies to potions

The text is very clear:

> Benefit: You may drink **a potion** as a move action instead of a standard action as long as you start your turn with **the potion** in your hand.

It would be up to you and your DM to agree on a homebrew modification to the trait that allowed you to drink anything as a move action, in particular mead from the horn, in case you own the horn. (As it says this is *similar to* drinking a potion, that might help your case).

The feat [Potion Glutton](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Potion%20Glutton) would allow you to drink any potable as a move action, and [Two Fisted Drinker](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Two-Fisted%20Drinker) works to draw two potables as a move action and drink them both as a standard action. (Thanks to [willuwontu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/47188/willuwontu) for finding these!)

Comment: I felt that the last piece of text "though certain abilities can reduce the action required" might also be a reference to this Trait, since I can't find anything else that would reduce the action of drinking a potion, so if it doesn't reference this Trait, what could it refer to??

Comment: @Pethrax That's a good question, but I do not know the answer to that. I only know it is not Accelerated Drinker, as the rules are written.

Comment: @Pethrax [Potion Glutton](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Potion%20Glutton), [Two-Fisted Drinker](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Two-Fisted%20Drinker) are things that come to mind ...

Comment: @willuwontu Potion Glutton is an answer, just not one that works for my campaign, which to be fair wasn't specified in my question XD. Two-Fisted Drinker doesn't reduce the action economy, it simply expounds it, which isn't bad, just not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The Pathfinder 1st edition rules are full of things that are *like* something else, but not in every way.

In this case, they tell you all the rules associated with effect after the dash. The reference to *potion* is to simplify it the mind of the reader.

> Using 1 charge is similar to drinking a potion—it takes a standard action and provokes an attack of opportunity (though certain abilities can reduce the action required)

Alchemist extracts are also like potions:

> [fashioning magical potion-like extracts in which they can store spell effects](https://www.aonprd.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Alchemist).

But are forbidden from being used with Accelerated Drinker:

> Alchemist: Does the Accelerated Drinker feat from Cheliax, Empire of Devils allow a character to drink an alchemist extract as a move action?
> [No](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9ncw).